# How to format output as an html table?

Tags: html, node.js, forms, html-table

I have a simple node.js app that will gather user information using html forms. e.g name, city, state etc. So if I have 10 users who submitted their user information, I want this data to be displayed in an html table format. How do I achieve this? Answers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should upload your code here

Comment: There are about 67303759327 answers alone here on SO that demonstrate exactly what you asked about. None of all those answers helped? _Why not?_ And why should a 67303759328th answer make a difference?

Comment: @arhasha: As far as I know there are in total around 23 million answers on SO and not 67 billion (10^9). Still, an https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE would be appreciated.